# C++ code style auto formatting for tensorflow in CLion?

Tags: tensorflow, clion

I am writing some code for TensorFlow codebase and pulled their sources.

I use CLion for editing the code. In order to use the code auto-formatting feature, I went to
`Settings->Editor->Code Style`. There I choose `Set from...->Predefined Style->Google`. I suppose this should implement [these guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html)?

However, when I hit `Ctrl-Alt-L` for autoformatting in the original files, the code gets significantly reformatted. That means that either IDE does not implement guidelines properly or the codebase does not follow those guidelines.

Is there a way to get code formatting for TensorFlow codebase working properly? 
I know that you can import code formatting options from a file. Does anyone know where to find this file for TensorFlow codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLion implementation of Google Code Style can be inconsistent with the guidelines you mentioned. Just because Google Code Style was designed for formatting options that are available in ClangFormat tool. Lucky you! The latest CLion version supports external formatting by ClangFormat. Just [activate the option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/clangformat-as-alternative-formatter.html) and check again!

Comment: Ah, yes! Seems like something exactly I needed! Thanks a bunch!